Multivariate LSTM plateauing on epoch 1 when batch size is greater than 1
Any help on this would be appreciated.
I am building a multivariate LSTM (3 outputs). If I set batch size to 1, the model iterates and converges to a nice solution. If batch size is set to anything greater than 1, it converges to a loss function that is 10x higher than the best solution I can get on a good model, and it converges on the first epoch. Multiple epochs do resolve this.
This only happens on my multivariate LSTMs, and has happened to me on two completely different datasets. If I remove two of the outputs, and reduce to a univariate LSTM, the model converges just fine, regardless of batch size.
I have adjusted the learning rate, the optimizer, tried batch normalization, and tried all combinations more and less complex layer and neuron structure. I cannot find any documentation anywhere on this type of problem.
Any conceptual guidance someone could provide would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!
